# Scammy _transfer method of ERC-20 token

Tags: erc-20, tokens, cpp-ethereum

```
 function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
 require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
 require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
 require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
 uint256 taxAmount=0;
 if (from != _taxWallet && from != _marketWallet1 && from != _marketWallet2) {
 if (from == uniswapV2Pair && to != address(uniswapV2Router) ) {
 _holderLastTransferTimestamp[tx.origin] = block.number;
 }
 if(to == uniswapV2Pair && from!= address(this) ){
 require(_holderLastTransferTimestamp[tx.origin] == block.number,"error");
 }
 }
 _balances[from]=_balances[from].sub(amount);
 _balances[to]=_balances[to].add(amount.sub(taxAmount));
 emit Transfer(from, to, amount.sub(taxAmount));
 }
```

Hi, every one, i am new to Solidity, any input would be appreciated.

is the block.number of the first buy transaction preventing us from selling in a subsequent transaction

is there any workaround ? like buying and aditional amount and selling the total amout of the 2 purchases in the same transaction ? or 2 different transaction but same block ?